# Javascript/jQuery pure javascript equivalent of code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking to translate this code into pure javascript so I don't have to use jquery:

```
$('#msg').show(0).delay(5000).hide(0);
```

What would be the javascript equivalent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```js
document.getElementById("msg").style.display = 'block';
setTimeout(function () {
  document.getElementById("msg").style.display = 'none';
}, 5000);
```

```css
#msg {background: #f90; width: 50px; height: 50px;}
```

```html
<div id="msg">
  Hello
</div>
```

I have given the CSS for demo purposes to be clear.

Answer (score -1):

An other version of Praveen code using opacity.

```
var p = document.getElementById('msg');

p.style.opacity = 1;

setTimeout(function() {
 p.style.opacity = 0;
}, 5000)
```

Comment: jQuery `hide` is _roughly equivalent to calling .css( "display", "none" )_.

Comment: In many case it will work just the same and in other case it might work while display none wouldn't. So still a valid option. No reason to down vote this

Comment: In many case yes. But display is the best option to use, it has been made for this purpose

Comment: Opacity is the better form of `visibility`. **1.** Opacity has less browser support than `display`. **2.** Opacity doesn't remove the element from the view.